# How to fix AWS Glue code in displaying count and schema of partitioned table from AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I'm trying to count the records and print the schema of my partitioned table (in a form of parquet). I'm doing it just in AWS Glue Console (since I dont have access to connect to a developer endpoint). However, I dont think my query is producing any result. See my code below. Any suggestion?

```
%pyspark
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "s3", table_name = "subscriber", push_down_predicate = "(date=='2018-12-06')", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

df = datasource0.toDF()
print df.count()
df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about using `print` in Glue... I would recommend use logging to print results. You can get the logger object and use it like that:

```
spark = glueContext.spark_session
log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info(df.count())
```

From the Job console you can then access to the logs of the specific Job execution. There you should be able to see your DF count for example.

You can see an example code with generated results in the below picture: 
[image]

Comment: Hi Vzzarr. Can I run the job without doing any ETL at all? Planning to use the console just to count the records of the partitioned (and filtered) tables and not doing any transfer to another table (to reduce runtime).

Comment: @tn.splinter yes you should be able to run the Job in Glue without doing ETL (except for the reading of data of course, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do any count ;) ). I recommend then to use 'Continuous Logging' with 'No filter' https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging.html in order to improve user's logging (in this case, your logging) and to have more logging messages, which should help you to visualise your logging messages

Comment: Hi @Vzzarr tried this but still to no results. Logs only display infos and warnings. Still cant find rowcounts. Here is my query:

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "s3", table_name = "subscriber", push_down_predicate = "(date=='2018-12-06')", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
df = datasource0.toDF()
logger.info(df.count())

Comment: Logs:          

Jul 2, 2019, 10:41:05 AM 19/07/02 02:41:05 WARN Utils: spark.executor.instances less than spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors is invalid, ignoring its setting, please update your configs.
Jul 2, 2019, 10:41:05 AM 19/07/02 02:41:05 INFO ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread
Jul 2, 2019, 10:41:13 AM 19/07/02 02:41:13 INFO GlueContext: GlueMetrics not configured
Jul 2, 2019, 10:50:25 AM 19/07/02 02:50:25 WARN ServletHandler: /api/v1/applications
Jul 2, 2019, 10:52:09 AM 19/07/02 02:52:09 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0

Comment: @tn.splinter I tried to reproduce the described code and updated the answer with a picture of the successful count. Let me know if that helps